# AWS Python script vs AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I downloaded the AWS cli and was able to successfully list objects from my bucket. But doing the same from a Python script does not work. The error is forbidden error.
How should I configure the boto to use the same default AWS credentials ( as used by AWS cli )
Thank you

```
import logging import urllib, subprocess, boto, boto.utils, boto.s3

logger = logging.getLogger("test") formatter =
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s') file_handler =
logging.FileHandler("test.log") file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
logger.addHandler(file_handler) logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# wait until user data is available while True:
logger.info('**************************** Test starts *******************************')
userData = boto.utils.get_instance_userdata()
if userData:
    break
time.sleep(5)

bucketName = '' 
deploymentDomainName = ''

if bucketName:
    from boto.s3.key import Key
    s3Conn = boto.connect_s3('us-east-1')
    logger.info(s3Conn)
    bucket = s3Conn.get_bucket('testbucket')
    key.key = 'test.py'
    key.get_contents_to_filename('test.py')
```

---

CLI is -->

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket testbucket --key test.py my.py
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give the cli command you are using and also include your boto code. Additionally, include the error output.

Comment: Where you running both commands on the same computer? Was it an EC2 instance with a role assigned, or were credentials provided via a local file?

Comment: Yes it an ec2 instance with a role assigned. But why it would work from cli command line and not from python script. Also here is the updated python script and bat file

Comment: Which line generates the error? Could you please show the error output.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible to use the latest Python SDK from Amazon (Boto 3)?  If so, set up your credentials as outlined here: [Boto 3 Quickstart](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html).

Also, you might check your environment variable.  If they don't exist, that is okay.  If they don't match those on your account, then that could be the problem as some AWS SDKs and other tools with use environment variables over the config files.

*nix:
`echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID && echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

Windows:
`echo %AWS_ACCESS_KEY% & echo %AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY%`

(sorry if my windows-foo is weak)

Answer (score 1):

When you use CLI by default it takes credentials from .aws/credentials  file, but for running bot you will have to specify access key and secret key in your python script.

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
access_key = 'put your access key here!'
secret_key = 'put your secret key here!'

   conn = boto.connect_s3(
        aws_access_key_id = access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
        host = 'bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com',
        #is_secure=False,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )
```